# Python script runs from command line, stopped working from Excel Shell

Tags: python, json, excel, cmd, gmail

I have a Python script that's been running successfully when executed from Excel on a remote server. I recently did some testing from my local PC, updating the Python script and testing via remote desktop.
Since then, when on the remote desktop the Python scripts work when executed from the command line, but stopped working when the same command is executed from within Excel.  Example of code:

```
'Get file from Gmail using a Python script
vPytnonDir = "C:\Projects\Python"
ChDir vPytnonDir  'Directory where python script resides
Dim wShell As Object
Set wShell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
wShell.Run "cmd.exe /S /C python GetGmail.py", windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

When I run "cmd.exe /S /C python GetGmail.py" in a command window (in the Python directory) the command works.
I've refreshed the credentials.json and token.json to have the same user access to Gmail.
I've put a pause in the Python script, and the execute window just flashes, apparently the script doesn't get to the pause.
I've created a stand-alone Excel with just the sample code - AND THAT WORKS!
This is driving me batty (can't say crazy, already there) - Any help would be appreciated.

THIS HAS BEEN RESOLVED!
When I had done testing from my local PC, I had connected to the server via the "E" drive, and somehow that had reset the default drive for Excel.  The ChDir command in the code wasn't working at all, I had to run ChDrive("C") to get things back to normal.

Comment: I would have thought that your command would be more like `wShell.Run "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C " & Chr(34) & C:\Somewhere\python.exe C:\ScriptDir\GetGmail.py & Chr(34)` You should always use full paths and extensions, instead of relying on possible changes of current directory, and environment variables. _Obviously it would be better if you also appropriately quote all of your paths too_.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Compo. The directory is changed to the folder where the Python scripts are located (see ChDir command), so there's no need to use full paths to execute the script.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem is something wonky with MS security.

Comment: So `python.exe` and `GetGmail.py` are both in the `C:\Projects\Python` directory, are they? And regardless of that, you should not be using the `/S` option with `cmd.exe`, you should properly quote the command string, instead of trying to bypass lazy quoting.

Comment: Thank you again,
I found the problem!
There were no problems with the quotes, when I had run the test on the server from my local PC I had linked to the server via "E" drive, and the default DRIVE had been changed, the ChDir command didn't work, it also needed a ChDrive("C") to reset the drive back to "C".

Comment: That's probably because you weren't using the `CD`/`CHDIR` command correctly, to change the drive and directory, in cmd.exe, you use the commands `/D` option. Open a Command Prompt window, type `cd /?`, `chdir /?`, `help cd` or `help chdir`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its usage information. Alternatively take a look, similarly, at the help information for the `pushd` and `popd` commands. In VB, there is a different/additional step, you'd use `ChDir` to change directory, and `ChDrive` to change drive.